# Is there a HTML5/ jQuery Spherical Panorama viewer that works with touch mobile devices

Tags: jquery, html, image-processing

I am in need to a Spherical Panorama viewer to put in in a Webb app, preferably in HTML5 or jQuery. The user has to have the ability to use there fingers to move around the Panorama.

Is anyone aware of anything like this that is available, for a small fee or better free?

Comment: try this
http://gardengnomesoftware.com/pano2vr_example.php
it has html5, what mobile browser need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for i think:

http://www.openstudio.fr/jquery.spherical.panorama/

Comment: Thanks roasted, when I Googled this before posting, this was one of the ones that came up and its perfect but when used on a mobile device you can't 'Scroll' around on the image :( although after further digging I found the follwoing that looks like it could work:

http://krpano.com/examples/

Its charged for but looks nice and works on Mobile :)

Answer (score 16):

It's an old question, but for who find it now (like me):
I think Pannellum is a great option, and it's under active development
- https://pannellum.org/
- https://github.com/mpetroff/pannellum

Comment: It's a real shame your answer isn't the accepted one. It saved my ass just now :)

Comment: @SibinGrasic, my answer came almost 3 late ;)