# Move Smartphone to view different parts of spherical panorama?

Tags: android, jquery, ios, html, three.js

Related:
[Is there a HTML5/ jQuery Spherical Panorama viewer that works with touch mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140698/is-there-a-html5-jquery-spherical-panorama-viewer-that-works-with-touch-mobile)

Indirectly related:
[Orbiting around the origin using a device's orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35023076/orbiting-around-the-origin-using-a-devices-orientation)

I am looking for a way to view different parts of a spherical panorama / equirectangular projection by moving the smartphone or tablet (PDA) in space.

Basically just like http://takemetotomorrowland.com/explore/bridgeway-plaza where different parts of the environment can be seen by turning the phone towards its direction in space.

Ideally I like to be able to view different parts of [this image](https://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/webgl_panorama_equirectangular.html) by moving the device in space. So turning and moving the device in real space to view the different parts of the projection on the web.

Now I know this is done with WebGL and a spherical panorama viewer like [Pannellum](https://pannellum.org/) but how is the part with moving the device in space done? Is there a library for that or is there a plugin for that?

What is this part of the device technology called that senses movements in 3D space and how can I translate those movements to HTML/JS?

Now I know this is not a specific programming question, I am sorry for that. But I am really looking for a plugin or library or at least find out the name of the sensor responsible for the movements of the device so that I can then work with it.

Comment: Are you looking for [DeviceOrientationControls](http://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/DeviceOrientationControls.js)? [Example](http://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_deviceorientation.html).

Comment: Please answer the question with the content of your comment. That is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you heaps! Would you know what steps to take to combine this with drag and swipe control, meaning users can either use the device orientation or they can drag the image and both types of control will work on the image. That is what I am trying to do. Not the question but perhaps you have a link? I am thinking about https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin and check with Modernizr for PDA and then have both control types, on desktop just drag/mouse.

Comment: OMG. I just checked. You wrote this! Amazing stuff. Thank you! Diving right into WebGL. Nice one!

Comment: For swipe control, try `OrbitControls` with the camera at ( 0,  0, 1 ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you are looking for has been inmplemented in  [DeviceOrientationControls](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/DeviceOrientationControls.js).

See [this example](http://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_deviceorientation.html).

three.js  r.73